# Pass variable value to another component in ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to show ionic components, which are buttons, based on the value of a variable stored in another component.

The variable is called **isPickupRequested**, a boolean stored inside my **home.ts**

I would like to show a request-button when the variable is equal to true and hide it when false.

**Home.ts**

```
. . .
export class HomePage {

  public isPickupRequested: boolean;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform, 
   private geolocation: Geolocation, public events: Events)  {
    platform.ready().then(() => {

      this.loadMap();
      this.isPickupRequested = false;
}
. . .
```

**request-button.html**

```
<button [hidden]="!isPickupRequested" ion-button (tap)="ConfirmPickup()">Set pickup location</button>
```

How can request-button component have access to isPickupRequested variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass a value of a component out to a parent component you will need to use [events](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter).

So from the child page do something like this:

```js
import { EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';


@Component({ 
  ...
})
export class ChildPage {
  @Output() pickupConfirmed = new EventEmitter();

  ...

  notifyPickupConfirmed() {
    this.pickupConfirmed.emit(pickUpId);
  }
}
```

Then in the parent page you can just catch the event in the template like you would with any other:

```html
<request-button (pickupConfirmed)="onPickupConfirmed($event)">
```

Comment: Thanks. So home is the child in your example, and request-button is the parent?

Comment: Given the way you described your code, I'm a little confused as to what is the parent and what is the child component for you, hence I purposefully avoided to show any such relation in my answer (I wrote it agnostic of your code) :). As long as you understand the fundamentals of emitting events on child components end handling events on parent components, you are good to go. Cheers!

Comment: I can't get it to work. 'Cannot find name output'. I this for ionic2?

Comment: Yes it is. I forgot to import it from `@angular/core`

Comment: Having a bit of trouble implementing it.

`export class HomePage {
  @Output() pickupConfirmed = new EventEmitter();
  public isPickupRequested: boolean;`

results in Duplicate identifier 'isPickupRequested'.

Comment: You are doing something wrong in your declarations, buddy. This is trivial, and totally beyond the scope of the original question. Just makes sure you don't declare it twice.